# Traditional mongoose query not working for me

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Im making this mongoose query to get my parent document, but found nothing.
Most of mongoose examples doesnt work for me, some one happends same?

My schemas:

```
Parent var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    cell: String,
    properties: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Property'}]

}, {
        timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'} 
});
mongoose.model('Contact', schema); 


var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        address: String,
        country: String,
        province: String,
        locality: String,
        partido: String,
        contracts: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Contract'}]
    }, {
        timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'} });
```

//  The query

```
    var query = Contact.findOne({'propeties._id': req.params.id});
        query.populate('properties');
        query.exec(function (err, item) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            console.log(item);
        })
```

Edit!

i realize that when i declare schema relation like this properties[Property] it works, but i need use this way properties: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Property'}]
becaus i just want store _id not all document.

Comment: mmh, why not using console.log instead of `handleError`?

Comment: `properties` is an array not object so `properties[index]._id` should work

Comment: @wrangler i dont know the index at that time, this query is exactly the same of documentation.